# Cloud Spanner administration UI, API also stopped working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

It stopped working my account at the present moment. Since there is no fault status, write it here.

Do you replicate with other accounts?

Because different ones of different regions also occur simultaneously, I suspects the trouble.

Comment: I do not see a question here. Could you please clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Excuse me. I wrote in a hurry so the information was running short.

I edited it.

Comment: Can you provide more info about the issue? I think the for situation like this, [#cloud-spanner slack channel](https://googlecloud-community.slack.com/messages/C49R7DSTH/) might be a good place to get prompt updates. 
General service status can be checked at [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I can now access UI around 20:00. It is fixed so I write the answer.